# is multi-stage workers allowed in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I need to know that how does Spark allow communication between worker nodes ?
All the tasks assigned to workers are from the master program, but can a worker's output be sent to another worker, so it can process the further steps on it ..

I am working on a case where there are multiple types of tasks to be carried out, suppose say tasks A,B,C.
For task C to be started, task A and B should be completed, but A and B can be done independent of each other. So, i need few workers for task A, and few for B, and they must call workers of task C, without involving the master. Please provide me insights on how this can be achieved.
Is this kind of a feature available in Yarn ?

Comment: What advantage would this give you? If you complete the tasks in stages, in order ABC, or BAC, won't that take about the same time as interleaving A, B and C?

Comment: Actually, It is like streaming, let's say for first request it is A1,B1,C1 and for second A2,B2 and C2.  So, if task A1 and B1 is finished then 2nd stage of workers can execute C1 while 1st stage of workers can go on to execute A2 and B2.

Comment: I think it can actually make sense in some scenario. However @DNA has a point with his argument. At the end, not very much of the Spark distribution potential is used.

Answer (score 0):

I am just throwing a possible solution, although I have not tested it myself and I am unsure of its success possibilities.

What comes to my mind is creating a kind of barrier between the *B* and *C* tasks by making use of an action such as *count*. This will force *Spark* to complete all previous steps -in all nodes- before starting with stage *C* (I am not very sure of this statement).

You could then use the broadcast functionality to cache a variable and make it available for all executors without having to communicate with the master.

Answer (score 0):

I would give like to give a shot for the possible answers for this question. In my opinion this can be done in two ways:

1.) If the tasks A and B are independent and need to be completed before C, why not first perform tasks A and B on your RDD and then use the result of these tasks (or new rdd) and perform C using another action.

2.) Inter worker communication is a problem in spark (AFAIK). Only ways of communication in spark are broadcast and accumulator variables. But both of them are useful for driver-worker communicataion, not worker-worker communication. One possible workaround would be to save the result or variables from worker to a common storage such as HDFS and access it from another worker. For e.g. in PySpark there are efficient ways of communicating from worker machine to HDFS using Popep, Pydoop, Hadoopy etc.